# Export from Altium to simulate in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, simulation, schematics, altium, import

I need to simulate a complex schematic I designed in Altium Designer.
I chose LTSpice because Altium cannot simulate much behaviors, but I don't know how to export a format compatible with a format I can import in LTSpice as a schematic (.asc).

Is that possible? Or are there any other free softwares to do this?

TY

Comment: Does Altium have a way to export a “SPICE netlist”?

Answer (score 2):

It is not as simple as that. First of all, you need to have all the spice models for each components you have. If you have that, why not use the spice simulator in Altium, it is as powerful as LTspice.

Second, exporting between software is never perfect. I doubt that Linear made a converter from Altium. So I doubt you'll find anyway to convert one to the other.

Third, nowadays, it is harder to simulate full circuits due to programmable device. I found it is often better to simply simulate a sub circuit. I don't know your exact application.

Comment: I believe Altium uses ngspice as the underlying SPICE engine. Although I like ngspice a lot, I think LTspice is more powerful and more capable.

Comment: I saw that Altium isn't optimize for simulations but more for electronic design and I need to do many simulations such as which is necessary for european certification.
So it's essential for me to simulate the entire circuit, not by sub circuits.
Is there a way you know for this ?

Comment: I don't know what circuit you have nor which norm complies you to prove by simulation.  I'm not aware of many that accept simulation data over measurements, but I'm not an expert in international compliance. That being said, I find it very odd. As mentioned, simulating even not that complex design is basically impossible. With spice, you don't even take into account the layout. If you are at higher frequencies, you might need to do finite element analysis/sim. If so, you should look at other software such ADS or HFSS. At low frequency, I can't imagine why they would request sims.

Comment: Spice simulations not for high speed, but low noise (uV signals and pA-nA currents) are supremely useful. maintaining multiple files for a single analog front end so you can optimize in spice prior to your 2nd prototype, then tuning after testing. Easy to leave one thing out of date, so a simple translater from an altium netlist to a PSpice netlist for just the primitive comps, and just blank boxes for active devices would still help provided you enforce a unidirectional pull/update workflow in your vcs or plm...

Answer (score 2):

Altium designer doesn't have a format that you can import a graphical schematic into LT spice. If there is some way you could export the entire circuit as a netlist, it's possible you could simulate that in LT spice, but you lose the graphics. The best way would be to redraw it by hand. LTspice is simple and fast for drawing.

Comment: Yes but I cannot find components I need.
My goal is to replicate by myself an Arduino Uno by importing each component, what I manage to do in Altium but not in LTSpice.
Am I wrong ?

Comment: You can simulate analog in spice, digital components are not typically simulated.